# RSPEC NoMethodError: helper method calling another controller's action -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a controller file:

some_controller.rb:

```
class SomeController < ActionController::Base
    def get_params
      # Do something with params
    end
end
```

And a helper file:

```
module SomeHelper
   def modify_params
      get_params
   end
end
```

And rspec File for helper:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SomeHelper do
   describe 'check_if_param_has_key' do

   it "checks if param has key" do
     modify_params.should eql(true)
   end
end
```

Here, I am calling controller's method inside helper method. Now I am writing test cases for helper method `modify_param`.
But it throws error : `NoMethodError: get_params`

Is there a way to access controller's method inside helper spec?
Is this the right way to do it? Or Am I missing something in this?

**Edited:**
The controller is ApplicationController, and method inside it return string containing which controller/method was called on page load, by looking at params[:controller], params[:action]

Comment: Methods are not global. You cannot just access any method from any other location. So the short answer is: No, this is not possible. However, I would be happy to provide a suggested design if you share some more context about what these methods actually do.

Comment: It's not possible. Actually in your case it's not required too. When we are testing helpers code, we need not to call controller actions, you can stub those(because you'll test those actions in controller tests and integration tests). So all you need here is stubbing.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. I was thinking that since I am calling the helper method, it must be having context of controller's method which it is calling. I will check stubbing solution.

Comment: @TomLord - The controller is ApplicationController, and method inside it return string containing which controller/method was called on page load, by looking at params[:controller], params[:action]. I am using this method inside helper file to check if a particular method of controller is called based on which I do something on view side.

Answer (score 1):

As the author of RSpec has [pointed out](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/340#issuecomment-908887), helper tests are conceptually unrelated to controllers. So even if there was a way, you'd likely not want to bring the controller into the picture. You can easily stub out the method call in your spec:

```
describe SomeHelper do
  describe "#foo" do
    before do
      allow(helper).to receive(:bar).and_return("hello")
    end

    it { expect(helper.foo).to eql("hello") }
  end
end
```

Even if you had a controller, you'd likely have to stub the method call there, to cover the edge case.

Note that this stubbing a method not defined in the helper will fail if you're using verifying doubles.

Answer (score 1):

My problem has been solved by making get request to the page:

```
describe 'check if the home page by checking params', :type => :request do
   it 'return true if page is Home page' do        
     get "/homepage"
     helper.modify_params.should eql(true)
   end
end
```

In above code, after calling get request to homepage, helper method will have access to all the params and controller action it is calling. All my test cases have been passed.